# How to let search engines know which part of page is for mobile?

Tags: seo, responsive-webdesign

Some parts inside my page (like div or section, not full page) are duplicated − content is the same, but visibility changes depending of viewport. Is there any tag which lets search engines identify main and alternate parts?

Comment: Nope, you should address the issue rather looking for a Google band-aid.

Comment: With responsive content there should be no need to duplicate anything on the page, why exactly are you having to repeat the same content?

Comment: I have a class for DIV which adds to inner DIVS same height. Well, sometimes on mobiles it's not okay, so I need to hide it

Answer (score 2):

Don't duplicate content in a web page. 
That's **rarely appropriate for human readers** and thats how the Google bot will view and analyse your entire page as a whole. You risk it concluding that you are doing a mild form of "keyword stuffing".

If you want certain content to always be visible on screen on initial page-load (also known as 'above the fold') regardless of the size or orientation of the viewport then it is possible to redesign the page structure to allow that.

Comment: Seems like I'm not experienced enough in explanations. Here's example: `<div style="height:800px" class="hidden-on-mobile">Content</div> <div style="height:200px" class="hidden-on-desktop">Content</div> `

Comment: @DemuriCelidze , no problem, sometimes we all have to ask a few "wrong" answers to get to the real question we need to ask. In your case I suspect you are not using modern best practise to create a responsive web page. I encourage you to ask a new separate question about the best way to achieve your design giving plenty of detail about your html, objectives and any javascript you are using. Good Luck!

Comment: There should be no reason to use inline styling unless your loading it from the JavaScript DOM, furthermore there should be no reason why you should have 2 content containers. any benefit from having a responsive site will be undone due to duplicating content and in fact will give you worse rankings than before your site was responsive.

Comment: You should be using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to adjust the main container rather than simpling using hide this content for mobile, hide this content for desktop, this isn't to say that you shouldn't ever hide content, but generally you should try and display everything, and worse case hide... not hide it because its duplicate, as that's not valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mobile sitemap tag

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34648?hl=en

But it's referred to an url not a html element. And if you use ajax you can use this guide to properly set the content findability

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google now renders the page as the user would see it and indexes the content on the page that appears to users.   They render the page both as desktop and mobile user agents.    Google will get it right without you doing anything.   They will see the content on the page just once with any given rendering.   The mobile rendering will see the mobile content and the desktop rendering will see the desktop content.